# Python create list of objects from dict

Tags: python, list, loops, object, key-value

I am getting a dict of users and their information

```
{'Username': 'username', 'Attributes': [{'Name': 'sub', 'Value': 'userSub'}, {'Name': 'email', 'Value': 'email'}
```

I want to restructure this into an array of objects

ex) `[{username: 'username', sub: 'userSub', email: 'email'}, {username: 'secondUsername', sub: 'secondSub'...}]`

How do I accomplish this without manually putting in every value, as there may be different Attributes for each user

I have this so far

```
   for user in response['Users']:
        userList.append({
            'username': user['Username'],
            user['Attributes'][0]['Name']: user['Attributes'][0]['Value'],
        })
```

This will return the correct structure, but I need to dynamically add the user attributes instead of manually putting in each index or string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would initially create each `dict` with just its `username` key, then use the `update` method to add the remaining keys.

```
from operator import itemgetter
get_kv_pairs = itemgetter('Name', 'Value')
# e.g.
# get_kv_pairs({'Name': 'sub', 'Value': 'userSub'}) == ('sub', 'userSub')

user_list = []

for user in response['Users']:
    d = {'username': user['Username']}
    kv_pairs = map(get_kv_pairs, user['Attributes'])
    d.update(kv_pairs)
    user_list.append(d)
```